# Can access image in /assets via URL locally but not on heroku (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I added an image `whale.png` to `app/assets/images/whale.png` in a Rails app.

Locally I can access the image in the browser with `http://localhost:3000/assets/whale.png`.

But when I try the same thing on heroku, `https://my-app.com/assets/whale.png`,

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

And in the JS console,

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) whale.png

OR

> GET https://my-app.com/assets/whale.png 404 (Not Found)

Also tried:
- `https://my-app.com/assets/images/whale.png`

Why does this work locally but not in Heroku? Does heroku move the image to another directory?

Comment: Did you *precompiled* the assets?

Comment: In production the assets are precompiled, so the a checksum is appended to theimage name. Something like `https://my-app.com/assets/whale-checksum12345678asdfghjkl.png`

Comment: You can access it using `image_url`

Comment: So if I want to use it for FB Open Graph and need to reference the location, I should probably put it somewhere external like S3?

Comment: No, you should put in public folder. Every image in public folder is accessible without checksum because they are not precompiled